# How do I remove a range (subsection) of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a simple, always-consecutive-ordered list like this:

```
all = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] # same as range( 1, 7 )
```

I also have `current = 4`. In the end I want the `all` list to look like this

```
altered = [ 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
```

So what happened was it removed the `current` number and *the one before it* `3`.

`current` can also be `1` and `0`, so I want to make sure it doesn't throw an error for those two values.

For the exception `current = 0`, the altered list is like this

```
altered = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Which means that `current = 0` simply removes the last number.

I feel like you can probably code something fancy with generators, but I suck at writing them.

Thanks in advance!

**Bonus points** for doing this in one line. If the `current = 0` is too much trouble, then it could also be `current = -1` or `current = 7`.

**EDIT:** Make sure to check for `current = 1`, which should be

```
altered = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: When current==4 is the 4 removed from the list because it has the value 4 or because it is in the fourth position (when counting from one)?  Similarly, is the 3 removed because it is the smallest number less than 4, or because it's on the index preceding the removed item?

Comment: The list is always a `range()` so it doesn't matter whether you look at it as a position or value.

Comment: Don't call your lists `all` as there is a built in function `all()` and that removes access to it once you use the name.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
all = all[:max(current - 2, 0)] + all[current:]
```

or

```
del all[max(current - 2, 0):current]
```

Comment: Nice! This works for `current = 7` as well. Is it possible to make it so that it deletes the last number for `current = 0`? Then it'll be perfect!

Comment: I just simply did `if current = 0:` `all = all[:-1]`. It made the code simpler to read too.

Answer (score 5):

Would this work?

```
>>> all = range(1, 7)
>>> new = all[:2]+all[4:]
>>> print new
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all[:max(current-2,0)] + all[max(current,0):][:-1] + all[-1:]*(0 < current < len(all))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> all = range(1,7)
>>> current = 4
>>> [item for item in all if item != current and item != current-1]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> current = 0
>>> [item for item in all if item != current and item != current-1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: BTW This keeps the original  list unaltered.

Comment: `current = 0` must remove the final value `6` as **hobbes3** mentioned

Comment: I feel like this should work, but it doesn't for `current=0` :-( `[item for item in all if item != current and item != current-1 or current == 0 and item != len(all)]`

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that 6 was was removed as well. :p